# How to select top 75% of rows using SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, percentile, trino

I have a table with 3 columns: `user` (string), `home` (string), `num_events` (integer), like this:

```
user1,A,4
user2,B,5
user3,A,2
user4,C,12
```

A certain home can "contain" many users, but each user belongs to only 1 home.

I need to filter out all the first quartile of users with the lower num_events for each home. In order to do it, my plan is to list all users for each home, then order by num_events descending, and keep only the first 75%, then count the users for each home.

My attempts are similar to this:

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT home, user, num_events
FROM table 
GROUP BY home_cusec, user, num_events
ORDER BY home_cusec, num_events DESC
)

SELECT home, COUNT(distinct user) FROM t
WHERE num_events > APPROX_PERCENTILE(num_events, 0.25)
GROUP BY home
ORDER BY home
```

But none of my attemts ave been successful. Please note that I am using AWS Athena, and the function TOP is not registered, so I cannot use

```
SELECT TOP 75 PERCENT * FROM t
```

I have tried with

```
LIMIT (SELECT ROUND( COUNT(*)*0.75 FROM t)
```

But also with this the query is not valid in AWS Athena...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COUNT()` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY num_events DESC) rn,
              COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT user, home, num_events
FROM cte
WHERE 1.0*rn / cnt <= 0.75;
```

Comment: Note that for Presto/Trino using `1.00` instead of `1.0` can be important

Answer (score 1):

You can use [window functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html), particularly `row_number` and `count`:

```sql
WITH with_row_nums AS (
   SELECT *,
       row_number() over (partition by home order by num_events) row_num,
       count(*) over (partition by home) AS cnt
   FROM table_with_3_col
)

SELECT user, home, num_events
FROM with_row_nums 
WHERE 1.00 * row_num / cnt > 0.25; -- 1.00 is important here or use cast(row_num as decimal(18,2)) / cnt > 0.25
```

For example:

```sql
-- generate data 2 homes of 4 users each
with data as (
    SELECT user as user_id, user as num_events, home
    from unnest(sequence(1, 4)) as u(user),
        unnest(sequence(1,2)) as h(home)
),

-- query parts
with_row_nums as(
    select * ,
        row_number() over (partition by home order by num_events) row_num,
        count() over (partition by home) cnt
    from data
)

select user_id, num_events, home
from with_row_nums
WHERE cast(row_num as decimal(18,2)) / cnt > 0.25
order by home, user_id;
```

Output:

| user_id | num_events | home |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 |